# What does the following Azure Notification Hub REST response mean: 'The specified resource description is invalid.'?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, win-universal-app

*I am trying to register my Windows Universal App for notifications from the Azure Notification Hub through our Java backend service.*

I debugged the app from Visual Studio, while it was running on my Windows Phone device. The app could properly get a ChannelUri and passed it along to our Java backend. (I ran the backend on my local PC.)

The Java backend generated the following request for a template registration and tried to send it to the Azure REST Api:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   <content type="application/xml">
      <WindowsTemplateRegistrationDescription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <Tags>Windows,10204394042027091,broadcast</Tags>
         <ChannelUri>https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAABXiUp%2bD8v1%2bVfWbWLr3FZ3rQcJtPkUgFwaiGZus4GbtkM8zbZ6uQt1NKXpC4FOtYWHDxXvBb3FkoefaozvCYTFiDjhdb3jDuORUDY8zBlkGw1MxY0QjrH7G0fFbW0RXgo%3d</ChannelUri>
         <BodyTemplate><![CDATA[{...}]]></BodyTemplate>
         <WNSHeaders>
            <WNSHeader>
               <Header>X-WNS-Type</Header>
               <Value>wns/raw</Value>
            </WNSHeader>
         </WNSHeaders>
         <TemplateName>geoinfo</TemplateName>
      </WindowsTemplateRegistrationDescription>
   </content>
</entry>
```

In my opinion this is according to the MS Azure REST reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx

Still, the response contains the following error:

```xml
<Error><Code>400</Code><Detail>The specified resource description is invalid..TrackingId:4ffaabcc-c7f8-4a6c-ab2f-4f65e94427df_G16,TimeStamp:10/21/2014 9:42:52 PM</Detail></Error>
```

*Any ideas on what Azure's issue is around here?*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Call [Create Registration ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495626.aspx)
2. Store retrieved id in your DB
3. Call [Create or Update Registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495630.aspx) to create registration
4. Each time you want to update that registration in future (refresh channel, modify tags...) you just call Create or Update Registration again

I've just successfully played with payload bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2014-10-21T23:57:08Z</updated>
  <content type="application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8">
    <WindowsTemplateRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
      <Tags>t1,t2</Tags>
      <ChannelUri>https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AwYAAABXiUp%2bD8v1%2bVfWbWLr3FZ3rQcJtPkUgFwaiGZus4GbtkM8zbZ6uQt1NKXpC4FOtYWHDxXvBb3FkoefaozvCYTFiDjhdb3jDuORUDY8zBlkGw1MxY0QjrH7G0fFbW0RXgo%3d</ChannelUri>
      <BodyTemplate><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><root></root>]]></BodyTemplate>
      <WnsHeaders>
        <WnsHeader>
          <Header>X-WNS-Type</Header>
          <Value>wns/raw</Value>
        </WnsHeader>
      </WnsHeaders>
      <TemplateName>MyTemplate</TemplateName>
    </WindowsTemplateRegistrationDescription>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
  
My problem is that our flow is already in place for iOS and Android template registrations and it works just fine for those two.  
  
It is only the WNS registration that is not going through, which is rather weird. I have a feeling that something goes wrong between Azure and WNS, so first I will try connecting to WNS directly to see how that goes.

Comment: Well, the answer was actually hidden in your sample code: it is the capitalization:WnsHeaders instead of WNSHeaders.

Answer (score 1):

The error message apparently means that the request is missing required XML elements.
The problem in my case was the capitalization:

*Both **`WNSHeader`** and **`WNSHeaders`** should be written in Pascal case instead: **`WnsHeader`** and **`WnsHeaders`**.*

Unfortunately [Microsoft's documentation on the API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx) is misleading regarding this.