# WNS template registration gets rejected from Azure Notification Hubs

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm sending create or update **template registration** requests to my Azure Notification Hub using the **REST API**, but my requests **always get rejected** for template registrations for **Windows Notification Service** while it works for all other service types.

The body of my request looks correct to me, when I compare it with the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <WindowsTemplateRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
            <Tags>SomeTag:1,TEST_REGISTRATION</Tags>
            <ChannelUri>https://db3.notify.windows.com/?token=AgY7AABrfRCVgRV%2ba4DwoDjC2omrnOVwCkdhCrrzlJi6UpIwHzcig6%2fG5xZfnDqU0%2fXoE848ddiqyTaTlSSltp2Dn9Z3qaPsMAyh7kS%2bmlis1%2bwoh%2b%2b4DsAK1yeV1d9G1rUIuFs%3s</ChannelUri>
            <BodyTemplate><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><data><title>$(title_en)</title><message>$(message_en)</message><notificationType>1</notificationType></data>]]></BodyTemplate>
            <WnsHeaders>
                <WNSHeader>
                    <Header>X-WNS-Type</Header>
                    <Value>wns/raw</Value>
                </WNSHeader>
            </WnsHeaders>
        </WindowsTemplateRegistrationDescription>
    </content>
</entry>
```

ANH always returns the **response code 400** (*Invalid request body. The registration could not be created because the request was malformed.*), but using this format works for all other service types (e.g. GCM, MPNS) and I can create a WNS template registration manually using the Service Bus Explorer with the exact same ChannelUri, template and WnsHeaders.

What else could be wrong here? Is there any way to debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in this question: [What does the following Azure Notification Hub REST response mean: 'The specified resource description is invalid.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497103/what-does-the-following-azure-notification-hub-rest-response-mean-the-specifie)

"**WNSHeader**" needs to be written in Pascal case, like this: "**WnsHeader**", so the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223265.aspx) is not 100% correct...

Comment: Thanks, the error I got that this fixed was `Must contain WNS Header : 'X-WNS-Type'`.

Comment: Filed bug for documentation error https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/issues/20